# Identify each select option individually using simple JavaScript or jQuery and show in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a PHP code that actively generates a Select input with 5 different options in it.

Now, I also want to show the  number 2, 3, 4 and 5 in a div as text as well.

Note that I want to ommit the first option in my DIV.

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
```

Also to be displayed accordingly:

```
<div><img src="#" /> 2</div>
<div><img src="#" /> 3</div>
<div><img src="#" /> 4</div>
<div><img src="#" /> 5</div>
```

I tried doing this with document.forms[0].select.value; but it only shows the selected value and not all the options. Furthermore, I want to filter the first option so what should I do? Any help is appreciated.

---

Actual HTML of the `select` element, provided by OP in comments to an answer:

```
<select class="last" id="property_types" name="property_types">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">View all Property Types</option>
    <option value="96" class="level-0">Apartment</option>
    <option value="9" class="level-0">Building</option>
    <option value="3" class="level-0">Land</option>
    <option value="97" class="level-0">Office</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('option').slice(1).each(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text(),
            outputTo = $('#output'),
            div = $('<div />').text(text),
            img = $('<img />', {'src' : '#'}).prependTo(div);
        div.appendTo(outputTo);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wJUVm/).

Note that this assumes a specific `div` is used in order to contain the output of this approach, obviously adjust to taste.

Above code amended to provide a specific selector, in response to the OP's posting code in the comments to this answer:

```
$('#property_types option').slice(1).each(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text(),
            outputTo = $('#output'),
            div = $('<div />').text(text),
            img = $('<img />', {'src' : '#'}).prependTo(div);
        div.appendTo(outputTo);
    });​
```

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
- [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: I would've suggesting something similar, but why the slice? I would skip the sli cing and just empty the <select> afterwards. Readability improvement + not convinved that slice will work here.

Comment: The `slice()` is simply to prevent the first option being acted upon; and it *seems* to work okay. Albeit currently only tested in Chrome 19, Win XP.

Comment: Hmmm point taken. Bit confused why the first one is already handled and not hte else, but you're right since it was in the question.

Comment: In real life I guess the first `option` might be the `Select one of the following` (or similar) 'prompt,' rather than an 'option' as such?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!

Only question, how can I limit this to a specific <select> and not all?

Comment: You can pass an `id` into the `$()` to refine the selector, such as the `id` of the `select` itself or a parent element. But without seeing your actual mark-up, it's difficult to say.

Comment: <select class="last" id="property_types" name="property_types">
 <option selected="selected" value="0">View all Property Types</option>
 <option value="96" class="level-0">Apartment</option>
 <option value="9" class="level-0">Building</option>
 <option value="3" class="level-0">Land</option>
 <option value="97" class="level-0">Office</option>
</select>